# Asyncio Stopping/pausing

Tags: python, graphql, python-asyncio

I'm trying to achieve that once the condition is met in `print_handle(data)` I want to pause the current async, create a new async request with my `query2`, close that request, then continue with the first one.

```
from python_graphql_client import GraphqlClient
import asyncio
import os
import requests

headers={'Authorization': "2bTxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}

def print_handle(data):
    print(data["data"]["liveMeasurement"]["timestamp"]+" "+str(data["data"]["liveMeasurement"]["power"]))
    tall = (data["data"]["liveMeasurement"]["power"])
    if tall > 100:
        print("OK")
        #pause the current async thread, create a new one with the 
        #query2, close that one, and continue with the first. 

client = GraphqlClient(endpoint="wss://api.tibber.com/v1-beta/gql/subscriptions")

query = """
subscription{
  liveMeasurement(homeId:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxa"){
    timestamp
    power
  }
}
"""

query2 = """
mutation{
  sendPushNotification(input: {
    title: "Varsel! Høy belastning",
    message: "Du bruker nå høyere effekt enn 5 kw, pass på forbruket",
    screenToOpen: CONSUMPTION
  }){
    successful
    pushedToNumberOfDevices
  }
}
"""

async def main():
    await client.subscribe(query=query, headers={'Authorization': "2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}, handle=print_handle)
    
asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Take a look to this[1]. It will allow you to synchronize threads. I'm not sure if this is what are you looking for, but maybe it helps.

[1]: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html

Comment: Please note that these are synchronization primitives for asynchronous programming. They do _not_ synchronize threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing multithreading and asynchronous programming. You do not want to pause your thread because that would mean you would pause your whole program.
I take from your code that you want to send a push message once some condition depending on your data is met. I don‘t think you need to pause anything for that. It can be as simple as scheduling a task for sending that message. You could go with something like this:

```py
from python_graphql_client import GraphqlClient
import asyncio
import os
import requests

headers={'Authorization': "2bTxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}

def print_handle(data):
    print(data["data"]["liveMeasurement"]["timestamp"]+" "+str(data["data"]["liveMeasurement"]["power"]))
    tall = (data["data"]["liveMeasurement"]["power"])
    if tall > 100:
        print("OK")
        # schedule async task from sync code
        asyncio.create_task(send_push_notification(data))

client = GraphqlClient(endpoint="wss://api.tibber.com/v1-beta/gql/subscriptions")

query = """
subscription{
  liveMeasurement(homeId:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxa"){
    timestamp
    power
  }
}
"""

query2 = """
mutation{
  sendPushNotification(input: {
    title: "Varsel! Høy belastning",
    message: "Du bruker nå høyere effekt enn 5 kw, pass på forbruket",
    screenToOpen: CONSUMPTION
  }){
    successful
    pushedToNumberOfDevices
  }
}
"""

async def send_push_notification(data):
    #maybe update your query with the received data here
    await client.execute_async(query=query2) #pass whatever other params you need

async def main():
    await client.subscribe(query=query, headers={'Authorization': "2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}, handle=print_handle)
    
asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Thank you so much, and you're completely right, I'm abit confused about how graphql works and multithreading/async.  This works perfectly!! (after passing the header along with the query2)

Comment: @AlexanderBrandhaug Glad it helped. Feel free to accept and upvote if the answer solved your problem :-)

Comment: accepted, but I dont have enough points to be able to upvote it, sadly. Thanks anyways! :)